# ASP.NET MVC ModelBinding with $ajax vs $post and using Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

Ok, I couldn't find anything with my exact problem, so hopefully someone can fill me in on this.  I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 (targeting 4.5.1 Fx) and using KO 3.0 and the latest jQuery.  I have a KO model that has a few properties more than the .NET model it represents (2 computed observables only needed in the view and not in the backend).  The scenario is the user makes some changes and hits a Save button.  This calls a method in the KO VM that uses jQuery to post back to the server and save the changes.
The Controller method looks like so:

```
public void Post(Profile profile)
    {
        var modifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var existingProfile = db.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == profile.Id);

        ...     

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

My KO method looks like so:

```
self.updateProfile = function (profile) {
    $.post("/api/profile", profile, function () {
        alert('saved');
    });
};
```

Now this works just fine, but if I try to change to use $ajax method (which is what I'd like for more fine grain control), it fails.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/profile",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            profile: profile
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('saved');
        }
    });
```

The object profile in the Controller method isn't bound to the data sent by the $ajax method.  I'm not sure why, as $post is just a high-level abstraction of $ajax.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With the debug console open, how do the two request headers differ?

Comment: looking at the 2 different requests now using the WebForms Inspector in Fiddler 4, I see that the $post method has the values Id: value, OwnerId: value, etc, where as the $ajax method has profile[Id]: value, profile[OwnerId]: value. So clearly this is the issue.  What does the $post method do that I need to replicate in the $ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data: {profile: profile},` is where the two snippets differ. you likely want `data: profile` instead.

They also differ here: `dataType: "json"`, but that's ok if your server is returning json.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/profile",
    type: "post",
    //dataType: "json", optional, you can keep it if you want.
    data: profile,
    success: function () {
        alert('saved');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I had been used to posting multiple parameters and just thought the {} and naming the parameter was required.

Comment: Also, just as a tiny piece of info, you can replicate `dataType: "json"` in `$.post` with one more parameter: `$.post(url,data,successHandler,"json")`

Comment: Hi,  Any idea how can I pass multiple parameter using $.ajax?  I tried below but in vain- $.ajax({
    url: "/api/profile",
    type: "post",
    //dataType: "json", optional, you can keep it if you want.
    data: {
              param1: profile1, param2: profile2}
    success: function () {
        alert('saved');
    }
});

Comment: Found very nice article.  http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods  This explains how to pass multiple complex object to MVC controller.